# Binding causing negative values beeing passed to Rect.ctor

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

so I am observing some strange behaviour that I cannot explain myself. I have the following UserControl:

```
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Margin="50 25 50 25">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding DataContext.SetcardTitle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindowEditor}}}" Style="{StaticResource editorLabelStyle}" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

        <Border Grid.Row="1"  BorderBrush="{DynamicResource AccentBaseColorBrush}" BorderThickness="3" >
            <xctk:Zoombox x:Name="zoombox" Style="{StaticResource editorZoomboxStyle}" >
                <Canvas x:Name="myCanvas"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ClipToBounds="True" Width="{Binding LiveImage.ViewablePicture.Width}" Height="{Binding LiveImage.ViewablePicture.Height}">
                    <Canvas.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding LiveImage.ViewablePicture}"/>
                    </Canvas.Background>
                    <Rectangle Stroke="Cyan" StrokeThickness="3" RadiusX="100000" RadiusY="1000000"  Width="{Binding ROI.Width}" Height="{Binding ROI.Height}" Canvas.Left="{Binding ROI.X}" Canvas.Top="{Binding ROI.Y}"/>
                </Canvas>
            </xctk:Zoombox>
        </Border>

        <ListBox Grid.Row="2"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  MinHeight="100" Margin="0 10 0 0" ItemsSource="{Binding Images, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource imagesListItemStyle}">

            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

Running the application like this causes the following exception when the usercontrol is loaded (The first line says: Width and Height must be non negative):
[image]

To prevent this exception I have to remove the Binding of the Label Content completly.

Does anyone know whats happening here?

**Edit**
It looks like that something in the Extended WPF Toolkit changed to cause this. I reverted back to an older version where everything works fine and as it should.